# how to debug a web service in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

Please correct me if I did anything wrong:

1. I created a web service (WSDL) in Java and it has a method `TestCall()`.
2. I also created a website http://testwebsite:8000/abc/index.html, and this website is calling the web service in step 1.
3. I created a remote debugging for it in IntelliJ. I put testwebsite as the host and 8000 as the port number.
4. Once I went to http://testwebsite:8000/abc/index.html and click on `TestCall()`, it didn't go to the breakpoint in IntelliJ. When I was trying to remote debug the web service, I got error:

   > Unable to open debugger port (testwesite:8000), handshake failed, connection permanently closed.

Can someone tell me what steps I missed? thanks

Comment: The debugger port should be something other than 8000, if i understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to remotely debug an application, go to the settings (`Run->Edit configurations`) in IntelliJ.

Now click the `+` sign and add a `Remote` configuration. It tells you the command line to add to the startup of the JVM you start on the remote machine. It will be something like:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005` for jvm 5-8.

Now you can start your remote web service on the server with these extra command line options. Then you start this configuration in IntelliJ. It will tell you `Connected to target VM, address: 'server name', transport: 'socket'`. You can add breakpoints as you are used to with local debugging.

As you see: the remote debugging does not use the web-port, but a different port that is opened especially for debugging purposes. If there are firewalls between the server and your workstation, please choose a port that is open, or have the firewall port opened (if possible).

Comment: If I don't use remote debugger, and just need to do unit testing for the web service, what's the correct approach? create a simple console application and call the method inside the web service?

Comment: @msProgram: If you need unit tests, you should look at jUnit or TestNG. I prefer jUnit with Mockito. In the unit tests you can test the class itself, without the whole server around it. But take notice: a unit test should just test ONE class: not the dependent classes. These should be mocked out and tested separately. If you want to do it totally correct you can look at TDD (Test Driven Development): You first create a test and after this the class. Unit tests normally are run as part of the maven build.

Comment: thanks. That should work. I am using maven build actually.