# How do I debug a Java app running in a Docker container in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2?

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I have a Java app that I'm attempting to debug inside of (because a particular error only happens when the app is run from inside `Docker`, which is *fun*), but I can't figure out how to get IntelliJ to attach for debugging.

I have the Docker Integration plugin installed, but when I go to run my container, the deploy log has a line that says `Cannot retrieve debug connection: Debug port not specified`.  Google told me that I needed to add a `debugPort` entry to my `workspace.xml` file, but when I did *that*, my Run/Debug configuration complained that "Debug port forwarding not found".  Clicking "Fix" resulted in a `container_settings.json` file being created, which IntelliJ immediately informed me wasn't supported in 2017.3+, and that i should use command line options instead.  However, I have no idea what those command line options should be.

When I tried specifying the forwarding port in the Run/Debug configuration, the deploy log ended with `Cannot retrieve debug connection: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: unix`, which makes *no* freaking sense.

Help!

Comment: You have to enable remote debugging on the Java process inside 
your Docker image. Then remote connect to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799330

Comment: Robert's suggestion is generally correct. Also if you want to be able to deploy the application (war, ear) to remote application server you can use corresponding app. server's Run/Debug Configuration of a **Remote** type, e.g. [JBoss Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html) Remote.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use dcevm / HotswapAgent in dockerized application and modify code/resorces without restart. Look at this project https://github.com/HotswapProjects/hotswap-docklands